# How to change user-agent/application name when connect to PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, connectivity, client

I use AWS RDS, and there is top application tab in perfomance insight like below sceenshot

[image]

TablePlus is a SQL client that I used. If I run query using that app, it shows TablePlus in that tab. But if I run with my application that use golang or PHP programming language, it shows unknown. How does it works? Can I change that programmatically or using SQL query?

I want to change it because I want to know if there is unknown application connect to my database server. But currently my own application detected as unknown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the displayed name by running a SQL statement:

```
set application_name = 'My cool app';
```